# ValueError at / The view leads.views.home_page didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead python django template error how to fix

Tags: python, django, django-templates

ValueError at /
The view leads.views.home_page didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

this is my code:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home_page(request):
    
    # return HttpResponse('Hello world')
    render(request, 'leads/home_page.html')
```

and here's the urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from leads.views import home_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_page),
]
```

and here's the template:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here

```
def home_page(request):
    render(request, 'leads/home_page.html')
```

[`render` combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an `HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) object with that rendered text. So you have to return this `HttpResponse` back from view.

```
def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'leads/home_page.html')
```